# ValueError while fitting a neural networks model on Consumer Complaints data

Tags: neural-networks, model, natural-language, lstm

I am trying to build a keras tensorflow neural network model. I have never built a NN model prior so facing challenges with some very basic error.

I Was able to build the model using following code. I Am not adding packages for sake of brevity.

```
    %%time
    
    # prepare text data for LSTM
    max_features = 20_000
    MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH = 25
    tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=max_features, split=' ')
    tokenizer.fit_on_texts(df2["cleaned_text"])
    X = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(df2["cleaned_text"])
    X = pad_sequences(X, maxlen = MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH)
    y = pd.get_dummies(df2['category_id']).values
    
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y, 
                                                        stratify=df2["category_id"],
                                                        test_size = 0.2, random_state = 43, shuffle=True)
    print(X_train.shape,y_train.shape)
    print(X_test.shape,y_test.shape)
    
    vocab_size = len(tokenizer.word_index) + 1
    
    # build model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Embedding(input_dim=vocab_size, # Size of the vocabulary
                        output_dim=50, # Length of the vector for each word
                        input_length = MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH)) # Maximum length of a sequence
    model.add(SpatialDropout1D(0.5))
    model.add(LSTM(15, dropout=0.5, recurrent_dropout=0.5))
    model.add(Dense(20,input_shape=Y_train.shape, activation='softmax'))
    model.add(Dense(20, activation='softmax'))
    model.add(Dense(num_top_labels,activation='softmax'))
    #model.add(Dense(1))
    model.compile(loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', 
                  optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.001), 
                  metrics = ['accuracy'])
    print(model.summary())
```

After this when I fit the model usign below piece of code, I Get the

> ValueError: Classification metrics can't handle a mix of multiclass
> and multilabel-indicator targets.

First time it occured at 21st Epoch, 2nd time at 25th epoch.

```
batch_size = 64

class_weights = compute_class_weight(class_weight = "balanced", classes = np.unique(Y_train), y = Y_train)
class_weights = dict(zip(range(num_top_labels), class_weights))

#print("class_weights: ", class_weights)
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, 
                    class_weight=class_weights, # fix class imbalance
                    epochs = 25, 
                    batch_size=batch_size, 
                    validation_split=0.2,
                    callbacks=[
                      EarlyStopping(monitor = "val_loss", patience = 10, restore_best_weights = True),
                       ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=0.2, patience=2, mode='min') 
                    ]
                   )

y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
print('Accuracy:', accuracy_score(Y_test, y_pred.round()))
print('F1 score:', f1_score(Y_test, y_pred.round(), average='weighted'))
print(classification_report(Y_test, y_pred.round()))
```

How can I fix this?